# Missing file in ticcutils

Tags: github, nlp, artificial-intelligence, clone, mbt

While using the **timbl**, in **ticcutils,** I realize that the **commandLine.h** *file missing*. Is it something that I can go about?

```
Timbl.cxx:36:10: fatal error: ticcutils/CommandLine.h: No such file or directory
   36 | #include "ticcutils/CommandLine.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Upon running the make command for timbl, I ran into an error that commandLine.h was not found.

I was expecting that upon cloning the ticcutils from github, the file would be present. HOwever, it is not.